# Is there a Pixi equivalence to Konva's Konva.Path API?

Tags: pixi.js

I am looking for a way to create a shape in Pixi similar to how you can do it in Konva using SVG path data. I have tried to search the documentation but I haven't seen anything similar. Would appreciate any information that could point me in the right direction. Here is a Konva example to demonstrate what I am looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.2.0/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Path Demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      let stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      })

      let layer = new Konva.Layer()

      let path = new Konva.Path({
        x: 50,
        y: 40,
        data:
          'M33.5647 93.3012C29.4724 98.5807 24.7371 100.83 20.0375 99.7261C15.3379 98.6224 10.9154 94.2225 7.40371 87.1572C3.89202 80.0919 1.47148 70.7238 0.489 60.3956C-0.493475 50.0673 0.0125561 39.3092 1.93457 29.6631C3.85658 20.0171 7.0959 11.9782 11.1883 6.69871C15.2806 1.41923 20.0159 -0.829829 24.7155 0.273882C29.415 1.37759 33.8376 5.77741 37.3493 12.8427C40.861 19.9081 43.2815 29.2762 44.264 39.6044L26.754 47.9209C26.5575 45.8552 26.0734 43.9816 25.371 42.5685C24.6687 41.1555 23.7842 40.2755 22.8443 40.0548C21.9044 39.834 20.9573 40.2838 20.1388 41.3397C19.3204 42.3956 18.6725 44.0034 18.2881 45.9326C17.9037 47.8618 17.8025 50.0135 17.999 52.0791C18.1955 54.1447 18.6796 56.0184 19.3819 57.4314C20.0843 58.8445 20.9688 59.7245 21.9087 59.9452C22.8486 60.1659 23.7957 59.7161 24.6141 58.6602L33.5647 93.3012Z',
        // fill: 'green',
        // stroke: gradient,
        strokeWidth: 5,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        scaleX: 2,
        scaleY: 2,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: -50, y: -50 },
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: 50, y: 50 },
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'blue', 1, 'gold'],
        strokeLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'blue'],
        strokeLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: 40, y: 40 },
        strokeLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: 40, y: 8 }
      })

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(path)

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```